# Why does iTunesConnect ask for export compliance for every iOS app submission?

Tags: ios, encryption, app-store-connect

Although I like the new iTunes Connect interface, there's a massive let down on my app: it will ask for my encryption compliance form each time I submit a new binary.

In the "old" iTunes Connect website, it was only asking if the encryption scheme changed (and required a new form, which is understandable), here I have to provide it for every single binary I want to submit.

This slows down the validation process for about 3-4 days each time, which is really frustrating.

Does somebody have the same issue?
Is there a solution to skip this step ?

Comment: No, but I want to find that form and cannot. I had an app rejected because I forgot about the for,! I just resubmitted a rejected binary thinking I would be presented the form but no such luck. Anyone know how to get at the form?

Answer (score 1):

Each submission could end up live on the store and each change could have export implications.

You could not update things if it's a hassle to do the paperwork, but I don't see any chance that this will be relaxed due to the severity of the penalties Apple would face if they didn't ask and a developer did add content that needed to be classified according to U.S. Law.